# Random number generator utility class

Tags: c++, random

I have implemented a utility class to perform various random number related task. I am looking for any feedback on design / implementation. I plan to expand the class, and so would like to correct any "bad habits" and or improve the basics before I proceed.

**Random.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <gsl/gsl> // gsl::narrow (for safety)

#include <random>
#include <cstdint> // uintmax_t
#include <chrono> // For DefaultSeed generation
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator> // std::distance

namespace ae
{
    namespace details
    {
        template <typename T>
        inline constexpr bool IsCharacterV
        {
            std::is_same_v<T, char>
         || std::is_same_v<T, signed char>
         || std::is_same_v<T, unsigned char>
         || std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>
      // || std::is_same_v<T, char8_t> C++ 20
         || std::is_same_v<T, char16_t>
         || std::is_same_v<T, char32_t>
        };

        template <typename T>
        inline constexpr bool IsRealV{ std::is_floating_point_v<T> };

        template <typename T> 
        inline constexpr bool IsIntegerV{ std::is_integral_v<T> && (!IsCharacterV<T>) };

        class DefaultSeeder
        {
            using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

        public:
            auto& operator()() noexcept
            {
                return this->seed;
            }

        private:
            std::seed_seq seed
            {
                {
                    Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(),
                    Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
                }
            };
        };
    }

    template 
    <
        typename Engine,
        typename Seeder
    >
    class BasicRandom
    {
    public:
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Ranges
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Integer range
        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]] 
        static std::enable_if_t<details::IsIntegerV<T>, T> range(T min, T max)
        {
            const std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(min, max);
            return distribution(engineInstance());
        }

        // Real range
        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static std::enable_if_t<details::IsRealV<T>, T> range(T min, T max)
        {
            const std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(min, max);
            return distribution(engineInstance());
        }

        // Call integer or real range according to common_type
        template <typename T, typename U>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto range(T min, U max)
        {
            using common_type = typename std::common_type_t<T, U>;
            return range(gsl::narrow<common_type>(min), gsl::narrow<common_type>(max)); // gsl::narrow will throw if the cast changed the value of its paramter
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Choice(s)
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto choice(T first, T last) // Uses range(x, y) internally
        {
            const auto distance{ std::distance(first, last) };
            const auto rand{ range(0, distance - 1) };
            return *std::next(first, rand);
        }

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto choice(T container) // Uses range(x, y) internally
        {
            return choice(container.begin(), container.end());
        }

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto choices(T first, T last, std::size_t amount)
        {
            std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> results(amount);
            for (auto& val : results)
            {
                val = choice(first, last);
            }
            return results;
        }

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto choices(T container, std::size_t amount)
        {
            std::vector<typename T::value_type> results(amount);
            for (auto& val : results)
            {
                val = choice(container.begin(), container.end());
            }
            return results;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Misc
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto shuffle(T first, T last)
        {
            std::shuffle(first, last, engineInstance());
        }

        template <typename T>
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto shuffle(T& container)
        {
            std::shuffle(container.begin(), container.end(), engineInstance());
        }

        template <typename T> // Use floating point values for T..
        [[nodiscard]]
        static auto chance(T p)
        {
            const std::bernoulli_distribution distribution(p);
            return distribution(engineInstance());
        }

    private:
        [[nodiscard]] 
        static Engine& engineInstance()
        {
            static Engine engine{ Seeder{}() };
            return engine;
        }
    };

    using Random = BasicRandom<std::mt19937_64, details::DefaultSeeder>;
}
```

Here is some example usage, that ive also used to make sure everything works as expected:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Random.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    const auto int_range{ ae::Random::range(0, 100) };
    const auto double_range{ ae::Random::range(0.0, 50.0) };
    const auto uint_range{ ae::Random::range(5u, 100) }; // std::common_type will make the result unsigned int

    constexpr auto chance_to_roll_6{ 1.0 / 6.0 };
    constexpr auto chance_to_roll_6_twice{ chance_to_roll_6 * chance_to_roll_6 };
    const auto roll_6_with_dice{ ae::Random::chance(chance_to_roll_6) };
    const auto roll_6_with_dice_twice{ ae::Random::chance(chance_to_roll_6_twice) };

    std::array<double, 5> my_values = { 1.6, 2.5, 1.73, 3.51, 53.21 };
    const auto random_element{ ae::Random::choice(my_values) };
    const auto only_first_three_elements{ ae::Random::choice(my_values.begin(), my_values.begin() + 3) };

    const auto multiple_choices{ ae::Random::choices(my_values, 10) };
    const auto multiple_choices_only_first_2{ ae::Random::choices(my_values.begin(), my_values.begin() + 2, 10) };

    std::vector<int> my_vector(10);
    std::iota(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), 0);
    ae::Random::shuffle(my_vector);

    std::cout << int_range << std::endl;
    std::cout << double_range << std::endl;
    std::cout << uint_range << std::endl;
    std::cout << roll_6_with_dice << std::endl;
    std::cout << roll_6_with_dice_twice << std::endl;
    std::cout << random_element << std::endl;
    std::cout << only_first_three_elements << std::endl;

    for (const auto& elem : multiple_choices) std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    for (const auto& elem : multiple_choices_only_first_2) std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    for (const auto& elem : my_vector) std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design would be cleaner with per-thread engines and free functions instead of `static` engines based on `<Engine, Seeder>`:

```
namespace ae::random {
    using engine_type = std::mt19937_64;

    inline engine_type& engine()
    {
        thread_local eng{/* seed */};
        return eng;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Consider giving uniform integer distributions and uniform real distributions different names, since they are essentially different: (expressed in concepts for brevity)

```
template <typename T>
concept int_type = /* T is [unsigned](short|int|long|long long) */;
template <typename T>
concept real_type = /* T is float, double, long double */;

template <int_type T>
T rand_int(T min, T max)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist{min, max};
    return dist(engine());
}
template <real_type T>
T rand_real(T min, T max)
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution dist{min, max};
    return dist(engine());
}
```

Consider constraining `choice`: (expressed in ranges for brevity)

```
template <std::random_­access_­iterator I, std::sized_sentinel_for<I> S>
iter_reference_t<I> choice(I first, S last);
template <std::random_­access_­range Rng>
range_reference_t<Rng> choice(Rng&& rng);
```

Similar for other functions.

The `choices` function can be made more flexible by providing a function for writing numbers to an `(out, count)` pair, or a range whose size is automatically deduced, and making `choices` a wrapper around it.

Also avoid `std::endl` when `\n` suffices.  `std::endl` flushes the buffer, while `\n` does not.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/9716597).

Comment: Thank you, would appreciate if you have time to add more.

Comment: @Cortex I've added more.  The code is pretty good in general, and upgrading to C++20 will take some time :)

Comment: Excellent, I guess the less you have to say the better im doing :D You have answered alot of my post btw, appreciate your effort!

Comment: @Cortex You're welcome.  Feel free to post more code for review in the future :)